# How to animate a column of objects removing the first one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have a problem with `.animate()`, `.position()` and `.offset()`.

I have a column (div - set width, height) of objects (article) with set width and different heights. What I want to do is animate the sequence: the new object appears at the bottom, the top disappears (`.remove()`) = all the articles are animated in the column towards the top of it. Something like 'scrolling' effect.

But `.animate()` does not change the `.position()` of the object, only the `.css()` values. So I cannot just iterate over the columns children take the previous position, set it using `.offset()` on the current one. Or maybe I'm wrong.